# Determine trend line types available in HighStock charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/vz4jrL58/19/) I have a Highstocks chart with two trend lines that I added programmatically, type = `trendline` and type = `sma`. This works fine:

```
 series: [{
        type: 'ohlc',
        id: 'aapl-ohlc',
        name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
        data: ohlc
 }, 
 {
      type: 'trendline',
      linkedTo: 'aapl-ohlc'
},
{
      type: 'sma',
      linkedTo: 'aapl-ohlc',
      params: {
        period: 10
      }
}]
```

What I need is to know all the types available. In the [Highcharts demo](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/stock-tools-gui) there's a dialog where the user selects the type, but it shows the type name/description but not the type that should be specified in the `type` attribute. How to know the identifiers of the types that are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All available series types with their properties, options and some examples you can find in the Highcharts API documentation.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series

And here is a link to the list of technical indicators: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/technical-indicator-series

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: perfect, in the second link there's an example for each technical indicator